# intent-filter + nfc.addMimeTypeListener re-opens the app again and again

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, nfc

I'm using the [phonegap-nfc](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) to perfomr all read/ write actions on NFC tags. The interaction with nfc tag is enabled only in few pages of the app.

Now I'm trying to add new feature i.e on tap NFC tag launch my app(when the app is not running) and do read action on the tag. Launching the app is working.

I have added intent-filter in **AndroidManifest.xml** as follows:

```html
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <data android:host="ext" android:pathPrefix="/<my-urn>" android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

and Added **nfc.addMimeTypeListener** as follows:

```js
nfc.addMimeTypeListener('text/any', function () {
  // route to particular page
}, function () {
  console.log('success!');
}, function () {
  console.log('Failed!');
});
```

I'm facing issue when I add *nfc.addMimeTypeListener*, if I just add intent-filter(without *nfc.addMimeTypeListener*), it launches the app and when I tap on NFC tag either it does nothing or it performs necessary nfc action based in which page I'm in - which is correct behavior. But when I add nfc.addMimeTypeListener in additoion to intent-filter, if I tap on NFC when the app is already open, it re-opens the app again and again instead of performing the necessary nfc action. Not getting what I'm doing wrong!

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can try removing listener and add mimeType in the manifest itself for eg `<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />`